# How can I make svcutil build a proxy to a schema with a jagged array?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

We publish the functionality contained in our business layer via a WCF SOAP service.
We use VS2008 and write the XSD using visual design tools ([XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/)) and generate the WSDL using [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/)

In one of our schemas we have what is effectively a jagged array:

```
<xs:element name="CriteriaGroups" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CriteriaGroup" type="SearchCriterion" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I generate a client, all calls to the service fail with this error:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'SearchCriterion[]' to 'SearchCriterion'
```

Common solutions on the net are to change the following line in `Reference.cs` from:

```
public SiDemSearchCriterion[][] CriteriaGroups
```

To:

```
public SiDemSearchCriterion[] CriteriaGroups
```

And all references from and to that property.

But that's no use because it may run, but it doesn't work.
It discards most of the data.
The setting to do it all as Lists just does nothing.

Any way to do this without changing the schema?
It's our schema so changing it is not *too* much of a problem.
I'd just rather not design it in a *"Microsoft Schema"* way.

The contract (WSDL + XSD) set is supposed to be platform independent and based on generic standards.

So:

1. Is there a way to make SVCUTIL build a working client without changing the schema?
2. How do I change the schema to make SVCUTIL build the client out of the box?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to not change the meaning of the schema, but just its layout? If you separate out the elements/complex types, into top-level components (instead of being nested), it may be easier for the tooling to cope with it. Note: this is just a guess, as I'm not familiar with your specific tooling.

Comment: Yes that's an acceptable change. The schema is still in the early stages of design.